# Xcode storyboard vibration with the new Trackpad

Tags: xcode

When I drag views around in the storyboard, the trackpad vibrates every time the view snaps to something else. As a result, it vibrates all the time. Is this a normal behavior or is my trackpad broken?

(How do I turn it off?)

Answer (score 3):

You can switch off Force Click & haptic feedback.

System Prefs > Trackpad > Point & Click

See Apple KB - [Using a Force Touch trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to disable the haptic feedback for Xcode alone? This feature might be useful in other apps/use case, even though it is annoying in Xcode storyboard.